# Adjective going with two examples that represent opposites

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I would like to know if there is a good adjective that can be used to describe two things that represent opposites. E.g.

> Anorexia and bulimia are two *[INSERT WORD HERE]* examples of eating
>   disorders.

Or maybe something less controversial:

> Two *[INSERT WORD HERE]* examples of colours are black and white...

Words that could make sense would be "polar" or "antipodal", but I am not sure if they can be used in this context.

Comment: I'd use "extreme":  *anorexia and bigorexia are two  extreme examples of eating disorders*. ***Extreme***:  at the furthest point, especially from the centre. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extreme

Comment: Thanks! I would actually like to stress more that they are opposites rather that they are extreme, if that makes sense. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: 'Opposite' (as you imply) and 'antonymic' don't sit well here, because the whole notion of 'oppositeness' is very complex. I think you're stuck with 'at opposite ends of the continuum' (where the continuum involved is easily recoverable).

Comment: You may use ***antithetical***: directly opposite or opposed - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithetical

Comment: How come bigorexia is an example of eating disorder?

Comment: @Rathony: good point, I changed the example.

Comment: And thanks guys, I guess antithetical will have to make do.

Comment: I would rather use *bulimia*.

Comment: 'polar opposites' is a good noun phrase for it.

Comment: Building on the above suggestions, '...are two _prime_, yet antithetical/polar opposite, examples of eating disorders.' If, of course, the text allows for such frivolities of the tongue.

Comment: Their is no "oppositeness" here at all. The example is poor because just because in one you binge eat and in the other you don't eat doesn't mean they are "opposites" medically speaking. They are only opposites semantically. The example is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ***[diametric](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diametric)***  (or, as it is often used, "diametrically opposed") may serve your purpose:

> 2:  completely opposed :  being at opposite extremes
>     *that husband and wife have seemingly diametric personalities, but somehow their marriage works*
>    <sub>from [Merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diametric)</sub>

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions! I think I go with "diametric" / "diametrically opposed" in the end.

Answer (score 1):

To signify that two things are on completely opposite sides of something else, the phrase ***diametrically opposite*** is used.
In your example, anorexia and bulimia are on completely opposite sides of *normal* eating.

> anorexia and bulimia are two ***diametrically opposite*** examples of eating
>   disorders

M-W:

> ***[diametrically opposite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diametrically%20opposite)***
>
> :  completely different : *They grew up in **diametrically opposite**
>   environments.*

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is, I think, **complementary**. While it has various meanings,

> either of two parts or things needed to complete the whole;
>   counterpart.

seems appropriate.

Answer (score -3):

Anorexia and bulimia are two contradictory examples of eating disorders.

Comment: How are they contradictory??  I don't see how this is a good fit at all.